# Shimano Gears won't shift

Tags: shimano, gears, shifter, cable, shifting

Basically when pushing the button to shift gear I can only get one speed up and one speed down. I tried adjusting derailer and the tightness on cables but it makes no difference.

Figured I'd make a video to explain it better
here you go.

thanks and  ask questions if needed

Comment: It doesn't load for me with the comment  "The uploader has not made this video available."  Even so, some text description of what you are trying to do and the problem is would probably be helpful.  It looks from the starting frame that you are adjusting it.

Comment: Oops, should work now, I'll add some info in the OP

Comment: Now I can watch the video, which I did.  It doesn't help at all.  I have no clue what your problem is.  Now the initial picture is not helpful, either.  Before it showed you adjusting a derailleur by hand.  Now it is nonsense.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @bill. I don't use Shimano much, but this kind of behaviour is common with older systems, and especially at the cheaper end of the range. It could be that nothing is wrong.

Comment: The video isn't helpful (we can't see whats happening), and we prefer things to be written out (so someone else can search for the question). see if the cable tension changes when you use the shift levers. If you hold the cable taut by hand after releasing the tension and apply the shift levers, you should be able to identify if this is the case or not. If not, you need new shifters (they're practically impossible to service, even if you have one to canabalize for parts).

Comment: Yes write the question out, but so many people asking questions don't know what terms to use correctly it's difficult to answer sometimes. The video was great!

Answer (score 1):

Can't really tell much by your video. We see you clicking up & clicking down, but you don't appear to be turning the cranks. The gears will not shift unless the drive train is in motion.

Comment: Well I could rotate the pedals but it would just show you the gear going up one and back down.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pull more cable through but the shifter is already in min gear after one click, while the derailleur is not.

The shifter needs to be in the correct gear (smallest cog) when you install the cable. So when the cable is un-done, you should repeatedly press the thumb shifter while pulling the cable until all the tension is released. Then tighten the cable pinch bolt and set up the rear derailleur as normal.

That's if you're reading this... And didn't get the issue sorted months ago.